Why jupyter hub spawner fails during startup
I have pulled the jupyterhub/jupyterhub docker image into my local machine. When i launch it, it asks a username and password that i don't know. What should be a defaut username and password ?
I tried username admin and password admin but it didn't work.
I tried a suggested stackoverflow answer as jovyan and jupyter but didn't work either.
I finally tried another stackoverflow answer suggesting to bash into the container and adduser there, but this is the error message i get:

